# Error converting data type nvarchar to int t

Tags: asp.net, sql

Below is my SQL stored procedure code. Please note it's a shopping website. When I am carting the products and giving discount on the sub total (like 2467 - 5% = 2345.65 is value returned) and then I click on proceed to payment, I get this error: `Error converting data type nvarchar to int`.

```
Line 211: int result = _com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here is my code:

```
create proc [dbo].[usp_ins_and_update_other_cart_details]
    @Guestid varchar(max),
    @DisAmount int,
    @ShipAmount  int,
    @SubTotal int,
    @GrandAmount int
    as 
begin
    if not exists(select Guestid FROM DiscountAndShippingdetails WHERE Guestid =@Guestid)
    begin
        insert into DiscountAndShippingdetails 
              ( Guestid, DisAmount, ShipAmount, SubTotal, GrandAmount ) 
        values(@Guestid,@DisAmount,@ShipAmount,@SubTotal,@GrandAmount);
    end
    else
    begin
        update DiscountAndShippingdetails 
           set DisAmount   = @DisAmount
             , ShipAmount  = @ShipAmount
             , SubTotal    = @SubTotal
             , GrandAmount = @GrandAmount 
         where Guestid     = @Guestid;
    end
end
```

Comment: You'll have to post your SQL query too.

Comment: What is this ?. You must show your effort. Here we don't know what you assigned for nvarchar and int. Even we don't know how to start with your question ?

Comment: Issue is not here. Issue is in your SQL query. Include varchar and nvarchar data in single quotes.

Comment: is 2345.65 SubTotal or Grand Amount ?. If so then your procedure might be wrong. You have to change data type or else you have to convert your values into int and then try inserting into database.

Comment: AFTER GIVING DISCOUNT 2345.65 IS GRAND AMOUNT I AM TRYING TO ROUND THIS VALUE LIKE 2345.65 IS 2346 IS THERE ANY WAY TO ROUND THIS DECIMAL VALUE PLEASE HELP

Comment: Have you tried with my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main error is only one thing, you declared data type as one, and sends your data as some other. See you have declared as int for all columns, but you are sending values as string. This is the main reason for your struggle. Please follow the below lines for your next step,

Change your declaration like this,

```
int subtotal = Convert.ToInt32( Math.Round(Convert.Todouble(lblsubtotal.Text)));
int discount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Convert.Todouble(lbldiscount.Text))); 
int shipping = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Convert.Todouble(lblScharg.Text))); 
int gradtotal =Convert.ToInt32( Math.Round(Convert.Todouble(lblGrandTotal.Text))); 
int ret= insertOtherdetails(guiid, discount, shipping, subtotal, gradtotal); 
if (ret != 0) 
{ 
   Response.Redirect("~/Checkout.aspx");
}
```

and change your function definition as , insertOtherdetails(string, int, int, int, int)

Comment: string subtotal = lblsubtotal.Text.ToString(); 
            string discount = lbldiscount.Text.ToString();
            string shipping = lblScharg.Text.ToString();
            string gradtotal = lblGrandTotal.Text.ToString();

            int ret= insertOtherdetails(guiid, discount, shipping, subtotal, gradtotal);

            if (ret != 0) 
            {

                Response.Redirect("~/Checkout.aspx");

            }


grand total is a asp lable with the name of gradtotal we have four lable subtotal ,  discount , shipping , gradtotal

Comment: dear now i get this Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'Cart.insertOtherdetails(string, string, string, string, string)' has some invalid arguments Source Error:


Line 384:            int shipping = Convert.ToInt32(lblScharg.Text);
Line 385:            int gradtotal = Convert.ToInt32(lblGrandTotal.Text);
Line 386:            int ret = insertOtherdetails(guiid, discount, shipping, subtotal, gradtotal);
Line 387:            if (ret != 0)
Line 388:            {

Comment: Change in your function definition also. if you find anything like this in your coding part insertOtherdetails(string, string, string, string, string) then please change like this insertOtherdetails(int, int, int, int, int)

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'Cart.insertOtherdetails(int, int, int, int, int)' has some invalid arguments source error : Line 386:            int ret = insertOtherdetails(guiid, discount, shipping, subtotal, gradtotal);

Comment: private string disCount(double rate)
    {
        return (Double.Parse(lblsubtotal.Text.ToString().Trim()) * (rate / 100)).ToString();
    } instead to change grand total is there any way to change this dicount decimal value to round it

Comment: Sorry change like this insertOtherdetails(string, int, int, int, int) and where you declared values to guiid ?

Comment: code is run now but giving this error Input string was not in a correct format Line 383:int discount = Convert.ToInt32(lbldiscount.Text);

Comment: code is run now but giving this error Input string was not in a correct format Line 383:int discount = Convert.ToInt32(lbldiscount.Text);

Comment: I have changed my code. Now i added Math.Round() function. Please check it. It will produce the output as you want.

Comment: new error now Compiler Error Message: CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Math.Round(double)' and 'System.Math.Round(decimal)'       Line 382:int subtotal Math.Round(Convert.ToInt32(lblsubtotal.Text));

Comment: string guiid=string.Empty;
     
            if (Request.Cookies["GuestInfo"] != null)
            {
                guiid = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["GuestInfo"]["GuestID"].ToString().Trim());
            } and now start this line int subtotal = Math.Round(Convert.ToInt32(lblsubtotal.Text));   int discount = Math.Round(Convert.ToInt32(lbldiscount.Text)); further so on now what to do brother

Comment: Change your coding part as of my new updated answer. Check it.

Comment: Check it again and execute. Finally let me know.

Comment: From Bottom of my heart i deeply thanking you rishy you really a master but so kind to get time for my problem which is now solve and resolve thanking you once again.

Comment: I will be here, no issues in this. And mark my answer as correct if you get satisfy, so that other can get into the thing easily.

Comment: dear how to mark when i am click on up button its say Vote Up requires 15 reputation and tmr ill come back in the morning again 10:30 with some problmes will you be help me out ??

Comment: I have a shopping website build on Dot Net which base price is on INR and i would like to make my website product price global currency like usd, euro, dinar etc etc is that possible to make this price changes dynamically base on country (IP) globally, or is there any live currency converter who could change my price to selected currency from drop down like this please help me out

Select Your Country : INR USD GBP EUR AUD CAD SGD NZD MYR FJD ZAR AED CHF LKR MU

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to check your string is not empty or null 
then convert it to integer.

If you want to convert nvarchar to integer from c# asp.net use following:

convert.toint32(yourstringvalue);

and if you do this from sql query
follow this:

CAST(yourvalue AS  INT)

===============
as you modified your post.
First check your stored procedure returns int / string
and then write

int result = Convert.ToInt32(executequery());

Comment: please take a look above

Comment: you need to add one output parameter "@ClientID INT OUTPUT" and then after insert / update operation set that parameter : SELECT @ClientID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: i still not get your point brijesh is there any way to accepted or refuse to take decimal value